# Pandas plot: using datafram columns as two-levels x-axis Minor and major tick-lables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

This is the data and code I use to generate the bar-chart below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [["2019","Jan.", 2000,2200,-200],
        ["2019","Feb.", 1500,1400,100],
        ["2019","Dec.", 1200,1100,100],
        ["2020","Jan.", 1400,1300,100],
        ["2020","Dec.", 1300,1200,100]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Year", "Month", "incomes", "expenses", "Balance"])
df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like however to use `df["Year"]` as the major tick-label and `df["Month"]` as the minor one, rather than the ordinal number.

How is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create labels by iterating through the dataframe, creating strings by concatenating the year and the month.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [["2019", "Jan.", 2000, 2200, -200],
        ["2019", "Feb.", 1500, 1400, 100],
        ["2019", "Dec.", 1200, 1100, 100],
        ["2020", "Jan.", 1400, 1300, 100],
        ["2020", "Dec.", 1300, 1200, 100]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Year", "Month", "incomes", "expenses", "Balance"])
ax = df.plot.bar()
ax.set_xticks(range(len(df)))
ax.set_xticklabels([f"{month}\n{year}" for year, month in zip(df["Year"], df["Month"])], rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: setting xtick labels for pandas bar plot]

Comment: You might want to add a line at `y=0`: `ax.axhline(0, color='black')`